# inclue link list category as css class

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, categories

I'd like to render some extra css classes in my wordpress links list, specifically id like to render the link category as a css class, so for example:

```
link       : http://www.foobar.com/
gategories : friends, colleagues
name       : Foo Bar
```

Currentyly renders as:

```
<a href="http://www.foobar.com/" target="_blank">Foo Bar</a>
```

But I want it to render as:

```
<a href="http://www.foobar.com/" target="_blank" class="friends colleagues">Foo Bar</a>
```

I know that you use the following function to build the links list but i cant work out how to modify it to do what I need:

```
function wp_list_bookmarks($args = '') {
    $defaults = array(
        'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC',
        'limit' => -1, 'category' => '', 'exclude_category' => '',
        'category_name' => '', 'hide_invisible' => 1,
        'show_updated' => 0, 'echo' => 1,
        'categorize' => 1, 'title_li' => __('Bookmarks'),
        'title_before' => '<h2>', 'title_after' => '</h2>',
        'category_orderby' => 'name', 'category_order' => 'ASC',
        'class' => 'linkcat', 'category_before' => '<li id="%id" class="%class">',
        'category_after' => '</li>'
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    $output = '';

    if(1) {
        //output one single list using title_li for the title
        $bookmarks = get_bookmarks($r);

        if ( !empty($bookmarks) ) {
            if ( !empty( $title_li ) ){
                $output .= str_replace(array('%id', '%class'), array("linkcat-$category", $class), $category_before);
                $output .= "$title_before$title_li$title_after\n\t<ul class=\"xoxo blogroll $category\">\n";
                $output .= _walk_bookmarks($bookmarks, $r);
                $output .= "\n\t</ul>\n$category_after\n";
            } else {
                $output .= _walk_bookmarks($bookmarks, $r);
            }
        }
    }

    $output = apply_filters( 'wp_list_bookmarks', $output );

    if ( !$echo )
        return $output;
    echo $output;
}

?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should never modify the Wordpress Core functions. In the case of Bookmarks, however, I don't really blame you for wanting to. They're kind of a pain.

I would just build it from scratch using get_bookmarks(). Here's a working example:

```
foreach(get_bookmarks() as $bm)
{
    $terms = get_the_terms($bm->link_id, 'link_category');
    $classes = array('wp_link');

    if($terms)
    foreach($terms as $term)
        $classes[] = $term->slug;

    echo '<a class="'.implode(' ', $classes).'" href="'.$bm->link_url.'"'.($bm->link_target ? 'target="'.$bm->link_target.'"' : '').'>'.$bm->link_name.'</a><br/>';
}
```

Just place this wherever it is in your template that you want to generate your bookmarks. Or you can wrap it up in a custom function call, and call that function from your template.